# Does having a NI number mean exercising treaty rights?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, europe, pakistani-citizen

Does having a NI number satisfy the exercising of treaty rights for the purpose of EEA visas in the United Kingdom?

Comment: Assuming you mean **National Insurance number**, it would mean you are registered with the UK National Health system.

Comment: Yes National Insurance number

Comment: An NIN is neither necessary nor sufficient to establish that someone is exercising treaty rights.  But what is the actual problem here?  It's not usually necessary to prove the exercise of treaty rights to get an EEA family permit.

Comment: really it is not important for Eea fm and residence card ?

Comment: for EUSS FP and then pre settled status

Answer (score 3):

An NIN may or may not be important for an EEA family permit or a residence card, depending on the circumstances.  In any any event, an NIN does not show that the person with the NIN is exercising treaty rights.  For example, someone could have an NIN and then move outside the UK.  They still have the NIN, but they're not exercising treaty rights.

Similarly, someone could be exercising treaty rights without having an NIN.  For example, someone who has just moved to the UK but hasn't yet applied for an NIN is nonetheless exercising treaty rights.

So, the answer to your question

> Does having a NI number satisfy the exercising of treaty rights for the purpose of EEA visas in the United Kingdom?

... is *no.*

However, UK authorities can use the NIN to find information about the person's presence in the UK, so they ask for the NIN to make it easier to evaluate the application.